# Pointer to this in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, this

I want to write a line of code that returns a pointer to `this`, because of an array (`std::vector<foo**>`). I thought of using a reference (`&this`), but it didn't work.

If any clarification is needed, let me know.

EDIT: To clarify what I'm doing, I'm trying to access the object directly using the array. Like so: `(*ARRAY.at(i))->foo("bar");`. Some people say it is impossible to make a pointer. If so, how would I access the object directly using the array?

Comment: `std::vector<foo**>` looks like a very bad idea.

Comment: `this` is a pointer, specifically to the instance of the object. To return a pointer to `this` implies changing the internal instance from outside the class. That would probably be bad. What are you really doing?

Comment: "*I thought of using a reference (`&this`), but it didn't work.*" Do you mean `*this`?

Comment: this IS a pointer already...you want another pointer to it..?

Comment: @AJG85, I'm trying to access the object directly using the array

Comment: ildjarn, that'd make &this, not **this

Comment: Sterling, how else can I access the object directly using an array?

Comment: @lkjoel : You're speaking nonsense.

Comment: ildjarn, uh, I compiled *this, and it gave me an error message saying "error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<foo**>::push_back(foo&)’"

Comment: Clarifications **are** needed.

Comment: @ikjoel I think you may want to clarify the problem you're actually trying to solve because asking how to make part of a bad implementation work without the details isn't going to generate good answers.

Comment: Ok, I will clarify on the question

Comment: If you just want to access it directly using an array, why can't you just put this into the array's element? somearrayofpointers[0]=this; ?

Comment: @lkjoel : `foo&` is a reference to a `foo`, which is what your question says you want.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't have a pointer to `this`, because it is not a variable, it is a reserved keyword that translates to a pointer to the current object.

In compilers implementation there may be a local variable of the function backing the `this` pointer, but it is an implementation detail and its address is inaccessible to the programmer.

What you are trying to do is *very* evil, but if you really really want to do it, you will have to create the variable yourself:

```
foo** evil_ptr_to_ptr = new foo*(this);
ARRAY.push_back(evil_ptr_to_ptr);
```

and some time in the future you will have to delete it:

```
// assuming you got all the elements in the array in the same way:
for(int i = 0; i < ARRAY.size(); ++i) {
  delete ARRAY[i];
}
```

Comment: @lkjoel using the address operator (`&`). It returns the address of the pointer on the stack of the current function.

Comment: @Richard, I tried that (`&this`), but it gives an error message: `error: lvalue required as unary ‘&’ operand`

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII - no. It is not possible to use the & on `this`. The  `this` pointer is not an l-value. It is an expression (albeit an special one), like `2+1`. It is like trying to compute `&(2+1)`, and in both cases, you will get the same error, that the operant of the unary & operator is not an l-value.

Comment: And whoever down-voted Ivella's answer is not aware of his own ignorance. Ivella's answer (like AndreyT's above) is correct (and ergo, +1 for it.)

Answer (score 4):

In C++ `this` is not an lvalue. For this reason it is not possible to create a pointer to `this`. For the very same reason it is also not possible to bind a reference directly to `this`.

Comment: Interesting. Why isn’t it a (const) lvalue though? It certainly looks like one (it has a name and all).

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph: Because when it comes to *rvalues* of scalar types, the concept of `const` does not apply at all. Rvalues of scalar types cannot be const or non-const. See 3.10/9: "Class rvalues can have cv-qualified types; non-class rvalues always have cv-unqualified types".

Comment: overloaded assignment operators regularly return a reference to `this` ... I guess that is an `rvalue`?

Comment: @Andrey My question was why it’s not an *lvalue*, though; not rvalue.

Comment: @AJG85 Overloaded operators return references to `*this` which is a different beast entirely.

Comment: @AJG85: Incorrect. Overloaded assignment operators regularly return a reference to `*this`, not to `this`. See the difference?

Comment: Ah yes, interesting never thought of `this` like this before.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph: Oh, I see. `this` used to be an lvalue at the beginning of C++. You could actually assign to `this` in class constructor, thus indication that you take over the memory management for class objects. However, this duty was relegated to `operator new` and `this` was changed to rvalue status. Frankly, I don't see any point in `this` being an lvalue. It would require  permanent memory location for each existing object? Why? For what?

Comment: @AndreyT There is no point. It’s *good* that `this` is an lvalue since it prevents errors. I’m just (slightly) confused why it’s a special case – it looks and feels like a variable and a straightforward implementation would just treat it as a hidden argument. Then again, it’s clearly not a normal variable anyway, and literals like `true`, `false` and `nullptr` aren’t lvalues either.

Answer (score 2):

> The this pointer is passed as a hidden argument to all nonstatic
>   member function calls and is available as a local variable within the
>   body of all nonstatic functions.

So, taking the address of the this pointer is effectively meaningless.

Consider this non-static member function:

```
void my_struct::my_func(int a);
```

When you call it on a my_struct the compiler do this under the hood:

```
void my_struct__my_func(my_struct* this, int a);
```

Given the fact that the this pointer is passed by-value, taking its address will give you the address of something that will not exist anymore after the function return.

Answer (score 0):

As other replies/comments pointed out, `this` is a pointer by itself.

Even if you could take a pointer to `this`: `this` is a local variable, local to the method you are running, and it is a pointer to the object you are working with.

Returning pointer to `this` would have the same effect as returning pointer to any other local variable: it will return garbage, because you've just left the scope where `this` was defined.

> EDIT: To clarify what I'm doing, I'm trying to access the object
>   directly using the array. Like so: (*ARRAY.at(i))->foo("bar");. Some
>   people say it is impossible to make a pointer. If so, how would I
>   access the object directly using the array?

Return `this`, store it in your array, and access like this: myArray[idx]->foo("bar")

Again, `this` is a **pointer** to your object.

EDIT:
I stand corrected. `this` is a rvalue expression implemented as hidden method parameter - which has a lifespan of a local variable. :)

Comment: `this` is *not* a local variable, `this` is a lvalue expression that evaluates to the pointer of the current object being called. That said, they are usually implemented as function parameter internally by the compiler, what is not visible to the user.

Comment: @lvella: `this` is an **rvalue** expression that evaluates to the pointer of the current object.

Answer (score 0):

You have plenty of correct answers by now, but try to think about it differentely:

Assume you have an object of your class `foo` allocated at some address in your memory. This address is effectively represented by `this` in the scope of your class. Now, you say you need yet another address to some variable that keeps the address of original object. This variable would have to be declared and have the lifetime of your object; obviously such a variable does not exist by default as it wouldn't make too much sense to create one. If you want to keep `foo**` in your container, you most probably have to keep another container of `foo*`, so the former can point to the latter. Well, again, most probably there's no point in doing so and I guess you should solve you problem differently? (You might like to present the problem on SO and get some help.)